# ImproperlyConfigured:You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path

Tags: python, django

I am new to django ! When I use the commad, `git push heroku master`  I get this error.

```
remote:        django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting
remote:
remote:  !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
remote:        See traceback above for details.
remote:
remote:        You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
remote:        Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
remote:
remote:           $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
```

My static files declarations are :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# set for the Heroku deployment.
import dj_database_url
DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://localhost')
}

#make reuqest.is_secure admit X-Forwarded-Proto
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

# support all the host header
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

#static configuration
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

My requirements.txt/runtime.txt/Procfile are all good, I googled a lot, Even tried the whitenoise, still I cannot fix it, so can someone help me? Thanks a lot!

My requirements.txt are like below:
dj-database-url==0.4.2

dj-static==0.0.6

Django==1.11.1

django-bootstrap3==8.2.3

gunicorn==19.7.1

pytz==2017.2

static3==0.7.0

IF I do `heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1`
I can push successfully, but the blog page does not show out because of some error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put in settings File `STATIC_ROOT` conf. The best you can do in production is serve static files through amazon s3 or another cdn so you don't overload your server.

[See the Django static files docs for more information.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/)